# Need INSERT QUERY for DATE column Values in Oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
INSERT
INTO TABLE_NAME
  (
    SEQ_ID,
    FIRST_ENTRY_DATE,
    UPDATE_DATE,
    TRIGGER_DATE,
    EMPLOYEE_NAME
  )
  VALUES
  (
    'I001247476',
    NVL('27/12/2014',SYSDATE),
    SYSDATE,
    TO_DATE('26/10/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
   'JHON'
  );
```

Date is coming in `DD/MM/YYYY` format but in query declared as `MM/DD/YYYY`.
How to handle this thing explicitly in query we cannot directly change the format or date in the above query.
**Any function available in oracle to handle this kind of scenarios?**

Comment: which column are you talking about? And what is the datatype of that column?

Comment: You can't change the string value being supplied, and you can't change the format mask in the statement? Really? If so there isn't anything you can do. Incidentally, why doesn't the second value have either a to_date or to_char (depending on the column data type), and why does the format mask for the fourth value expect a time to be supplied?

Comment: You are showing a query without any variables. But you say "date is comming in DD/MM/YYYY format". So is this query somehow generated with the date strings got? If so, where and with what programming language?

Comment: `NVL('27/12/2014',SYSDATE)` makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just swap the format mask around:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (
  SEQ_ID,
  FIRST_ENTRY_DATE,
  UPDATE_DATE,
  TRIGGER_DATE,
  EMPLOYEE_NAME
) VALUES (
  'I001247476',
  NVL( TO_DATE( :first_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY' ), SYSDATE ),
  SYSDATE,
  TO_DATE( :trigger_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY' ),
  'JHON'
);
```